# What are the limitations of computer plotting?

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions

The basic way of representing a function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  with a computer, crudely put, is "connecting a number of dots". We can improve the quality of the representation by increasing the number of dots.

While this method is great for the most usual functions, specially continuous or piecewise continous functions, there are cases where it isn't. As in numerical analysis, the most obvious issue with this approach is numeric precission, but I can think of a few other issues derived from irrationals and essential discontinuities. Maybe there is something such as "symbolic plotting", akin to "symbolic computation", but I haven't found any reference to it.

Is there a comprehensive list of these issues, or a paper caracterizing "plottable" functions?

Comment: Are after plotting algorithms or physical feasibility/meaningfulness of plotting a function ? What are the hidden thoughts behind your question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am sorry it is quite a general, broad question. I would definetely be interested in different plotting methods, but I am also curious if there is some sort of definition of plottable real function or just some informal guidelines. Probably, I can better explain myself through an example: graphing manually the characteristic function of the  $\chi_\mathbb{I}$ is just a matter of drawing two horizontal lines (y=1,y=0), but a computer typically would be able just to evaluate the function for rationals, thus graphing just y=0.

Comment: Your question seems to be more about finitely computable functions (or just numbers).

Comment: @YvesDaoust On the other hand, the popcorn function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) can (in my opinion) be fairly represented using just rationals. I'd say there is a very close relationship between continuity and "plottability" (which, I know, is not properly defined).

Comment: In a discrete universe, continuity doesn't make sense. On the other hand, plotting the sign function is not a problem. Taken in a strict sense, about no function is "plottable".

Comment: Upon thinking of this question, I still less understand what you are looking for. Care to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See these papers and the references therein:

- [Honest plotting, global extrema, and interval arithmetic](http://doi.org/10.1145/143242.143314), by Richard Fateman
- [From honest to intelligent plotting](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/220346.220351) by     Ron Avitzur et al
- [Efficient plotting the functions with discontinuities based on combined sampling](https://doi.org/10.14311/gi.17.2.2), by Tomáš Bayer
- [Reliable two-dimensional graphing methods
  for mathematical formulae with two free variables](https://doi.org/10.1145/383259.383267), by Jeff Tupper

Comment: Reviewing and understanding these will take me some time, but from the first's abstract, it seems that quite a big family of fuctions would be "plottable", thank you very much.

Comment: The paper by Ron Avitzur defines what I called "connecting dots" as "naive algorithm". It provides an example on page 2 where the function $f(x) = \sin(300x)$ is not properly depicted in the interval [-4,6]. This is caused both by a poor choice of sample points and a very ample interval, but it does prove the point that even simple functions cannot be plotted carelessly. Thus, I will tag your answer as the solution to my ill-asked question.

Answer (score 3):

My attempt: a function is said $\epsilon-$*plottable* if every point of its graph falls within a radius $\epsilon$ of some $(\hat x_i,\hat y_i)$, where $\hat x_i$ and $\hat y_i$ are numbers that admit a finite representation (such as, but not necessarily, floating-point), and no $(\hat x_i,\hat y_i)$ has an empty $\epsilon-$neighborhoohd.

---

This definition is not satisfactory, as it does not account for the fact that $\hat x,\hat y$ should be related by an equation similar to $y=f(x)$. But numerically, we don't have access to $f(x)$, and not even $f(\hat x)$.

Also, if $\epsilon$ exceeds the numerical resolution, by this definition any function is plottable.

Comment: Yes, it is this type of definition I was looking for, I actually like this one very much. Do you know if there is something similar in previous literature?

Comment: @Narciandi: not the slightest idea. The above definition is not right. The real issue is "are there points of the true graph that cannot be discovered by finite means" but this needs to be formalized.